# gcc 4.9.1 binding a c++ local variable to const auto ref

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

I found the most incredibly annoying binding problem that appears to be GCC specific.  I am not sure if this is me not understanding the rules of `const auto&` binding, or if the problem points to a gcc compiler specific bug.  By contrast, Visual Studio 2015's C++ compiler (Update 2 as of this writing) does not exhibit this unpredictable behavior.  I was able to reproduce problem with a minimalistic [**live coliru demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/258f015212c2b445).

The problem occurs if I bind auto variables to 'const auto&'.   In this case, it appears that the `const auto&` bound variable  binds to garbage.  If this is a user error (my not understanding the rules) could someone explain the rules about how I should do this to avoid such unexpected behavior.  The live demo shows an example of where I encountered the bug, I am not sure if this problem may be occurring in other places as I tend to use the `const auto&` binding whenever possible.

```
OptPairWrapper wrapper;
wrapper.setOptPair(std::make_pair(1,2));
const auto& badConstAutoRefBind = wrapper.getOptPair().get();
const auto goodConstAutoBind = wrapper.getOptPair().get();
// This line prints garbage
std::cout << badConstAutoRefBind << std::endl;  
// This line predictably prints (1,2)
std::cout << goodConstAutoBind << std::endl;
```

produced the following output

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lrt && ./a.out
(32767, 0)
(1, 2)
```

Comment: you are trying to tuse reference to destroyed temporary value. Don't be afraid of returning by value: in most cases `const Class var = someMethod();` will be optimized by copy elision instead of copy/move constructor or assignment operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `auto`.

`const` references can extend the lifetime of the temporary they're bound to. However, this only works when *directly* binding the temporary :

```
int foo() { ... }

int main() {
    int const &i = foo(); // Fine
}
```

In your example, you call `boost::optional<...>`'s `get()` function, which returns a lvalue reference. This reference is not a temporary, thus no lifetime is extended.

Comment: If `boost::optional<...>::get()` returns an lvalue reference to its member, then it's a subobject of that temporary, so the lifetime of the complete object should be extended as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki that would be very convenient indeed, but unfortunately it is not the case. Consider a (non-template) class with such a `get()` function defined out-of-line : there's no way to know whether the returned reference is bound to a subobject of the temporary `*this` from the outside.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki to be extra clear, you can extend the outer object's lifetime only by naming one of its members directly.

Comment: @Quentin Nice answer, but I am still a little confused as I don't know why the goodConstAutoBind worked in my example - the return value from boost::optional::get() is either (1) 'reference_const_type get() const' or 'reference_type get() (non const presumably)' - I saw this in the source code for boost::optional.  Doesn't that mean that given my const auto& - which binds to the first of these 2 possible return types and the second for the working assignment? Anyway the thing that really confuses me is why leaving out the & in my demo seems to successfully return the right thing?

Comment: @Quentin  contd... Is there some copy going on in that case?  This binding is a bit confusing.  Also I don't understand why is an lvalue reference not temporary?  I'm new to the nuances of binding so perhaps you can explain in fairly simple terms for me

Comment: @johnco3 sure thing ! `auto` works just like function template argument deduction. What happens is that it deduces the type of the initializer, *ignoring top-level const and reference*. You can then choose what these should be for your new variable. Thus, `auto const &` yields a `const` reference, while `auto` yields a value, that is indeed copy- (or move-) constructed from the initializer. The fate of the object inside the initializer is then irrelevant, sice you have a copy of it.